# Using Python requessts.post for creating Github repository cause "Problem in Parsing JSON"

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests, github-api

I am trying to use github api for an project. I am using the following python function for accessing github API and create an repository. But I get `status_code` 400. When I used with curl it works fine for the same api token and input parameters. But it causes this parsing json problem in python.
Heres the code:

```
import requests 
import json
import jwt

access_token = "..."

def create_repository():
    
    response = requests.post(
        url=f"https://api.github.com/user/repos",
        headers={
            # "User":user,
            "Authorization":f"token {access_token}",
            "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
        },
        data={"name":"simp2","private":False}
        
    )
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        out = json.loads(response.text)
        file = open("out.json","w")
        json.dump(out,file)
        file.close()
    else:
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.text)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_repository()
```

And I get the following output:

```
400
{"message":"Problems parsing JSON","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"}
```

What is causing this and is there any alternative or solution?
Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `data=` with `json=` in the `requests.post` call